# How does one compile and run a standalone executable JAR so that it can invoke Maven to run the parallel tests set up by Cucumber-JVM-parallel-plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins, cucumber

I am trying to execute parallel tests through the use of **Maven InvocationRequest, Invoker, and InvocationResult** components which are a part of maven-invoker dependency added into the pom.

Ultimately, I want **Jenkins** to run an executable jar which in turn executes the parallel tests. The code to programmatically invoke Maven to run the tests looks like this:

```
    InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();    
    request.setPomFile( new File("pom.xml") );  //pom is in the root level of the project
    request.setShowErrors(true);

    List<String> goalList = Arrays.asList("clean","install");
    request.setGoals( goalList );

    Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();

    invoker.setMavenHome(new File(System.getenv("MAVEN_HOME")));

    InvocationResult result = null;
    try {
        result = invoker.execute( request );
    } catch (MavenInvocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if ( result.getExitCode() != 0 )
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Build failed." );
    }
```

This code lives in the main class (i.e., **public static void main(String[] args**) ) which serves as the entry point when running the compiled executable JAR. The idea is that Jenkins will fire off something akin to this -->> "**java -jar MyCompiledTests.jar**" ... and this would run the code above which allows the tests to run in parallel.

This works so long as I use the pom location where the original project files reside. But, I am needing to compile a JAR which will live on an integration server and would be run by Jenkins daily (I do this with the current battery of tests but currently they all run in series). It seems that when I build the executable JAR (using maven-assembly-plugin), the pom file is not added to it.

So, the code above which *needs* to access the pom will return an error saying it cannot find the pom. To remedy that, I manually added the pom file to sit alongside the JAR in the given remote folder, but then when running this arrangement, I receive an error concerning the absence of the Features folder.

This error happens when the **Cucumber-JVM-parallel** plugin is reached during pom execution. Receiving this error stems from the fact that the pom file is now being read but the various path references within this plugin are not recognized because they are relative to the location of the *original project folders in Eclipse* and not the new remote folder location alongside the executable JAR.

Again, I can run things in Eclipse just fine and can even run the compiled executable JAR as long as I can point to the pom file which lives at the original project folder.

**The Question:**

- How does one compile and run a standalone executable JAR so that it
  can invoke Maven to run the parallel tests set up by
  Cucumber-JVM-parallel-plugin?
- How should the pom be referenced in the code above differently?
- Can the pom be wrapped into the executable JAR when it is compiled...or should it be?
- Is there a more elegant way to compile and run the executable JAR

I have searched far and wide, but either I am not seeing the answer right in front of me, or my intended goals for this executable JAR are unachievable given the current state of maven technologies.

Comment: Why not run the maven project directly in Jenkins using the Maven Project Plugin ?

Comment: Parallel test can be configured with maven-surefire plugin (I'm not 100% sure relationshop with Cucumber)..has nothing todo with MavenInvoker (apart from that `MAVEN_HOME` should not be used anymore). And better use Jenkins pipelines ...

Comment: @PengTuckKwok - I'll have to research that plugin.  But again the issue is that I develop using Eclipse on a local PC where I compile the executable jar.  From there, I copy this JAR to a remote server which a Jenkins build runs automatically every morning.  In the main class of the current JAR, the code programatically sets up a TestNG suite and executes the Runner classes one by one in series.  I want to run them in parallel and need to do so in a forked environment.  This is possible using the Maven-Surefire-plugin and the Cucumber-JVM-Parallel plugin, but it requires pom file accessibility

Comment: @khmarbaise - Indeed, I use maven-surefire-plugin along with Cucumber-JVM-Parallel plugin because I need to use JVM forks rather than threads because the web app I'm testing requires it.  And, all my tests run great as long as I am running the project within Eclipse, located on my local PC where all project files are developed OR I reference the pom file in the above code also back on my local PC where all the feature files exist in relative location.  Ideally, I was hoping to compile a jar and it would have all necessary files to run as a stand alone. However, the pom.xml never gets added.

Comment: @khmarbaise - Regarding the MAVEN_HOME comment, I am unaware of any deprication issues.  Again, I believe for this parallel scenario to work for me, the pom.xml must be present in some fashion and it currently dos not appear in the JAR file I compile (using maven-assembly-plugin).  Is the implication that I need to copy the entire project structure (i.e., pom file, features, step defs, etc.) to the remote server so that it can run?  It just seems odd that I cant access the executable standalone JAR to accomplish this....